# how to remove a layer of nesting from an array in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have a process that Im hoping to optimize: I have the following array

```
$journeys = [
    [
        'journey_id' => '123',
        'stops' => [
            'lon' => '123123123',
            'lat' => '123123123',
            'stop_name' => 'foobar st'
         ]
         ...
    ]
    ...
]
```

This array contains 1,000s of journeys, each with approx 40-50 stops in the stops array.

what I want to do is remove the nesting so I end up with something like this:

```
'stops' => [
    'journey_id' => '123',
    'lon' => '123123123',
    'lat' => '123123123',
    'stop_name' => 'foobar st'
]
```

At the moment the only way I can figure doing this is by looping over each item in the array and then each stop and creating a new array.

like this:

```
$stops = [];

foreach($journeys as $journey){
    foreach($journey['stops'] as $stop){
        array_push($stops, [
            'journey_id' => $journey['journey_id'],
            'lon' => '123123123',
            'lat' => '123123123',
            'stop_name' => 'foobar st'
        ])
    }    

}
```

This process is slow! does anyone know of a faster way I can do this?

Im using laravel, so collections are avaialble, though I tried that and it didnt seem any faster.

Comment: I think that is the way to do it. The question is: Do you need to do it? After all, there's no change in the information that is present.

Comment: If you need to change it, the best would be to change how it's generated so that the conversion process is no longer needed.

Comment: How are you creating the original array? Why not just create it structured as you want in the first place?

Comment: Since you aim for speed, how slow is this? maybe you could change `array_push(...)` to `$stops[] = ...` which eliminates a function call at each time of the loop. But this is still minor, there must be a bigger picture to this. Also below answers mention about collection and I don't see who they make it any faster, especially when you already said `Im using laravel, so collections are available, though I tried that and it didnt seem any faster.` Also, I do agree with above questions raised.

Answer (score 0):

you can collect it and then map on it, something like this:

```
$stops = collect($journeys)->map(function($v, $k){
                return $v['stops'];
         });
```

You can also make use of array_map, in case collection doesn't go well with you.

Comment: This answer is assuming the `$v` is a `stdClass`

Comment: Thats why I collected the array first. That converts it to a collection, if its a direct result from laravel model it must already be a collection.

Comment: He mentioned at the start it was an array.

Comment: @thisiskelvin And it's mentioned to collect the array first. :)

Comment: You wont be able to use the `->` syntax if it is an array first, only if it a collection from the laravel model

Comment: @thisiskelvin
You are correct, thanks for pointing that out, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using adding `$journeys` to a collection and using the `->map()` collection method to map what how the data should be returned:

```
$journeys = collect($journeys)->map(function ($journey, $key) {
    $journey['stops']['journey_id'] = $journey['journey_id'];
    unset($journey['journey_id']);
    return $journey;
})->all();
```

Here we create a collection of journeys. We loop through each journey, adding `journey_id` to the `stops` array, and unsetting the original `journey_id`.

When then return the new array using `->all()`.

**Note**: If using laravel eloquent models, use `$journeys->map(...)` as it will already be a collection instance.